# identify a string having special charactor

Tags: php, regex

I have no. of strings and i want to identify those string which have special characters.

I am trying this to do above

```
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $url)) {
    echo "special character";
}
```

And I have also tried:

```
if (ctype_alnum($url)) {
    echo "special character";
}
```

The character i want to allow are `a-z, A-Z, 0-9,_,-,/`

And my string containing special character is like

> torbjÃ¶rn-hallber etc.

how can i do that ? please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to tell if a string contains any special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256175/php-how-to-tell-if-a-string-contains-any-special-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt with `preg_match` was good, just don't negate the return value.

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $url)) {
    echo 'special character';
}
```

You want to allow more characters including `/`, so I use `~` as a delimiter.

```
if (preg_match('~[^a-z0-9/_-]~i', $url)) {
    echo 'special character';
}
```

Comment: [panther](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1595669/panther) I tried but its giving me a string - macvittie  as it have special character  and torbjÃ¶rn-hallber as a valid string inside if block.

Comment: @afeef: impossible, are you sure you removed `!` before `preg_match`? Both regex works.

Comment: panther got it now. but how to add more char in it ? bcoz when i do this (preg_match('~[^a-z0-9/_-.]~i', $url)) (added . as extra char ) it gives me a error Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 11

Comment: @afeef: dash has to be at the end, else the PHP try to use it as range between `_` and `.`. Use `~[^a-z0-9/_.-]~i`.